# PHP JSON Encode or Decode?

Tags: php, json, parsing, decode, encode

So I have some relatively simple JSON I'm trying to display using PHP and I'm getting stuck, I think perhaps I'm not using decode or encode correctly. Maybe I simply overlooked something.

Here's the JSON...

```
{

   "numFound": 43640,

   "start": 0,

   "maxScore": 0.7847167,

   "docs": [],

   "facets": {}

}
```

Here's my PHP...

```
<?php
$json_returned = file_get_contents("URL_OF_JSON_SOURCE");
$decoded_results = json_decode($array, true);

{
  foreach($decoded_results as $results){
 echo "Number Found:".$results['numFound'].";
 echo "Start:".$results['start'].";

  }

}

 ?>
```

I'm primarily just trying to get "numFound", "start", and "maxScore" to display. Thanks for any help, or even taking the time to read this post.

Here's the source JSON..
https://api.data.gov/gsa/fbopen/v0/opps?q=technology&data_source=FBO&limit=1&show_closed=true&api_key=CTrs3pcYimTdR4WKn50aI1GcUxyL9M4s1fyBbSer

Comment: where is `$array`? maybe you mean `json_decode($json_returned, true)`?

Comment: Why is your `foreach` wrapped in brackets?

Comment: Here's the source JSON https://api.data.gov/gsa/fbopen/v0/opps?q=technology&data_source=FBO&limit=1&show_closed=true&api_key=CTrs3pcYimTdR4WKn50aI1GcUxyL9M4s1fyBbSer

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any JSON Array in the given data. So firstly you don't have to loop returned data. Secondly you just forget double quotes in the loop. Third you don't have to join strings if you got any of them is null.

Here is the solution :

```
<?php
$result = json_decode( file_get_contents("sth"), true );
echo 'Number Found :'.$result["numFound"].'<br/>';
echo 'Start :'.$result["start"].'<br/>';
```

Comment: Works kind of but displays values as 0, here's the link to what it's supposed to return...

Comment: https://api.data.gov/gsa/fbopen/v0/opps?q=cat&data_source=FBO&limit=1&show_closed=true&api_key=CTrs3pcYimTdR4WKn50aI1GcUxyL9M4s1fyBbSer

Answer (score 0):

You php code is messed up

```
<?php
$json_returned = file_get_contents("https://api.data.gov/gsa/fbopen/v0/opps?q=technology&data_source=FBO&limit=1&show_closed=true&api_key=CTrs3pcYimTdR4WKn50aI1GcUxyL9M4s1fyBbSer");
$decoded_results = json_decode($json_returned, true);

echo "Number Found:".$decoded_results['numFound']." ";
echo "Start:".$decoded_results['start'];
?>
```

Comment: I gave it whirl and no luck..

Comment: @JohnChase I edited my code, try that. Worked for me